# iPhone/Objectivec-C float division incorrect output

Tags: ios4

In an IOS program i am trying to divide some float value but the result is incorrect

```
float a = 179.891891;
float b = 8.994595;
NSLog(@"Result %f",a/b);
```

On dividing the two  (a/b) the output i get is 20.0000 instead of 19.9999989993991 . I have tried using double instead of float but still the same issue . The value of "b" keeps on varying as i obtain it from some calculations . I need the result to be exactly precise as it further is required for some calculations and 20.0000 instead of  19.9999989993991 make a lot of difference in the final output i get .

Any help on this would be really great :).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know in Objective C, but in C, you should do casting:   (float)(a/b) .Otherwise it is integer division.